# Rename filename before uploading to SQL Server in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, rename

How do I rename files in C# before uploading the file in SQL Server?

I have tried this:

```
if (n.HasFile)
{
    string fileNameWithoutExtension=Path .GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CapitalStructureShareHoldingFile.FileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(n.FileName);
    fileNameWithoutExtension = "n" + extension;
}
```

For this file I want to rename it to `n` then its extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (ASPxUploadControl1.HasFile ) or//(Fileupload.Hasfile)
 {
     try
     {
         string extension = Path.GetExtension(ASPxUploadControl1.FileName);
         string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();  //here give your username or whatever you want
         string fileLocation = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", Server.MapPath("upload/"), id, extension);
         ASPxUploadControl1.SaveAs( fileLocation );
         StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
     }
 }
```

Comment: And now i want to write a loop that will collect all files from the method and upload them to db... Is it possible?

Comment: do you work on windows form application or ASP.NET @Anesu

Comment: it's been long time that i stopped working on entity framework but here's what i found hope this will help you https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uploading-multiple-files-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: you welcome, don't hesitate if you'll have questions i'm here i might help you @Anesu

Comment: could you please help on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093504/how-to-insert-files-in-an-array-to-sql-server-using-entity-framework-c?noredirect=1#comment102579432_58093504